# Multimedia Files on Linux

Tags: linux, debian, audio, multimedia

I'm very new to Linux environment. I have installed parrot security on my Acer Aspire E5 573G. I'm not much aware about using "linux as my daily driver" so when I try to run any multimedia file they don't run. I have vlc pre-installed but it won't open. When I try to watch videos on youtube there's no sound. Am I missing some drivers or something? I think all the necessary drivers are installed during the OS installation right? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

start VLC in the terminal and post the output, for audio try starting in `alsamixer` and see if the audio output terminal is set to MM, if MM press "M" on your keyboard

Comment: Audio is not set to MM. And all of this problem was happening when I logged in as root user. but if I work on my normal account everything works fine. any ideas why so?

Comment: VLC is just a problem, in fact, this is the error when trying to start it as root: VLC is not supposed to be run as root. Sorry.
If you need to use real-time priorities and/or privileged TCP ports
you can use vlc-wrapper (make sure it is Set-UID root and
cannot be run by non-trusted users first).